# Mongoose Installation Eroor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nvm

I am New to MEAN stack
I have installed mongodb on ubuntu and using node, express and npm via nvm.
While trying to do npm install for a project which has mongoose as dependency 
I get following Error

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-50-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/ehsan/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/bin/node" "/home/ehsan/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path /home/ehsan/.npm/ms/0.1.0
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/ehsan/.npm/ms/0.1.0'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/ehsan/.npm/ms/0.1.0']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/ehsan/.npm/ms/0.1.0',
npm ERR!   parent: 'mongoose' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ehsan/node/Tutorials/04/nodeAuth/npm-debug.log
```

but when I try to run this command with sudo
error apears that npm is not a recognized command (understandable)

Comment: If you are logged in as `ehsan` then you should have permissions to write to that location. Try to run `sudo chown -Rv ehsan /home/ehsan/.npm` to re-gain permisions if lost

Comment: Thanks, @Molda it solved this issue , and mongoose is being installed but doing `npm install`gives another error , I dont know two are related or not `> kerberos@0.0.15 install /home/ehsan/node/Tutorials/04/nodeAuth/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)`..

Comment: can you add the entire error to your question like the one you already have there?